# ffmpeg overlay duration issue

Tags: video, ffmpeg, overlay

I'm getting desperate trying to figure out why ffmpeg overlay filter misbehaves

I have the following ffmpeg command

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -r 60 -i ./tmp/tmp0.jpg -loop 1 -r 60 -i ./tmp/tmp1.jpg -y -filter_complex 
[0]trim=duration=5[0_trim0];
[0_trim0]scale=width=1280:height=-1[0_scale1];
[0_scale1]setsar=sar=1[0_setsar2];
[0_setsar2]crop=out_w=1280:out_h=720:x=0:y=(in_h - 720) / 2[0_setsar2_crop0];
[0_setsar2_crop0]setsar=sar=1[0_setsar3];
[0_setsar3]split=2[fl0_r0][fl0_r1];
[1]trim=duration=2[1_trim0];
[1_trim0]scale=width=1280:height=-1[1_scale1];
[1_scale1]setsar=sar=1[1_setsar2];
[1_setsar2]crop=out_w=1280:out_h=720:x=0:y=(in_h - 720) / 2[1_setsar2_crop0];
[1_setsar2_crop0]setsar=sar=1[1_setsar3];
[1_setsar3]split=2[fl1_r0][fl1_r1];
[fl0_r0]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[fl0_r0_];
[fl1_r0]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[fl1_r0_];
[fl0_r0_][fl1_r0_]overlay=x='if(lte(x, (main_w - overlay_w) / 2), -overlay_w + t / 5 * (overlay_w + (main_w - overlay_w) / 2), (main_w - overlay_w) / 2)'[tr0_overlay];
[tr0_overlay]trim=duration=5[tr0];
[fl0_r1][tr0][fl1_r1]concat=n=3:v=1[vt]
-map [vt] -acodec libmp3lame -r 60 -vcodec libx264 -f mp4 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset fast -crf 20 ./tmp/output.mp4
```

(It's padded for better visibility)

**What am I trying to do?**

1. show 1st image for 5 seconds(arbitrary number)
2. slide 2nd image over 1st image from the left to the right for 5 seconds(arbitrary number, can be 1, can be 10 - should not depend on the length of 1st and 2nd input streams)
3. show 2nd image for 2 seconds(arbitrary number)

**What do I get?**

I've tried various solutions, with this one 2nd image moves above 1st image just for the 1st second and then abruptly stops for the next 4 seconds after which instantly jumps to the end of animation

while ffmpeg spams lots of warning

```
frame=   98 fps=8.1 q=28.0 size=     144kB time=00:00:01.08 bitrate=1087.8kbits/
[Parsed_overlay_14 @ 0x30d6400] [framesync @ 0x30d64e8] Buffer queue overflow, d                                                                                                                                                    ropping
```

I suspect there is some issue with frames timelines, but so far I had no success
If I add setpts filter 5*PTS - it works perfectly but I observe 5x frame drop(from 60 fps down to 12 fps)
taken from: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Examples-88
(slow motion)

For some reason overlay filter works only with the 1st second of the video - no matter what I'm trying to do

I also tried to combine fps and setpts filter as a kind of weird hack - no success

ffmpeg version:

```
ffmpeg version N-76045-g97be5d4 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)
```

Probably I'm missing something obvious! 
Please help...

Comment: Could this be related? https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4950

Answer (score 0):

After ~8 hours of banging my head against the wall of ffmpeg, google and docs I finally found what to do(works with any sliding duration):

1. `setpts` filter `PTS*5-STARTPTS`
2. `fps` filter to correct fps to desired value after "stretching" the stream with `setpts` filter
3. pass both streams to the `fifo` filter, this prevents ffmpeg from dropping frames

for some reason ffmpeg drops ANY frames above FRAME_RATE given to the `overlay` filter unless you manually pass them thru the `fifo`...
i.e. at max you can pass 60 frames per second(if your fps is 60) or 12 frames at second for 5 seconds(60 frames in total = same as fps of the video)

bleh... I wish docs were better regarding such things

Answer (score 0):

So, If i got you correctly..
You want images to slide over previous image after some duration.

This is how you can do it:

> ffmpeg -loop 1 -i img01.png -loop 1 -i img02.png -loop 1 -i img03.png
>   -loop 1 -i img04.png -i watermark_logo.png -filter_complex \ "[0:v]scale=412x684,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];\
>   [0:v]trim=duration=3,scale=412x684,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,split[v1a][v1b];\
>   [1:v]trim=duration=3,scale=412x684,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,split[v2a][v2b];\
>   [2:v]trim=duration=3,scale=412x684,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,split[v3a][v3b];\
>   [3:v]trim=duration=3,scale=412x684,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v4];\
>   [4:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v5];\ [v0][v1a]
>   overlay=x='0':shortest=1[vv0];\ [v1b][v2a]
>   overlay=x='max(w-(t*w/0.5),0)':shortest=1[vv1];\ [v2b][v3a]
>   overlay=x='max(w-(t*w/0.5),0)':shortest=1[vv2];\ [v3b][v4]
>   overlay=x='max(w-(t*w/0.5),0)':shortest=1[vv3];\ [vv0][vv1][vv2][vv3]
>   concat=n=4:v=1:a=0 [video];\ [video][v5] overlay=main_w-80:main_h-80
>   [finalvid]" -i audio.mp3 -map "[finalvid]" -map 5:0 -t 20 output.mp4

**filter breakdown:**
- create v0,v1a,v1b... from input images
- overlay v1a on v0, v2a on v1b.. so on
- concat all overlay and generate video
- overlay video with water_mark
- map audio with finalVid